# Fetch mysql json data in const ENTRIES1 = []

Tags: php, react-native

I am a beginner in react-native. In my sample app i am using react-native-snap-carousel library where the slider is getting some static data mentioned in const ENTRIES1 = []. Now i want to make the slider dynamic. I created a php file which is generating json data from mysql server. Now how we can fetch those data in const ENTRIES = [] so that it can be displayed in the app.

As i am new to react-native, i have no idea for http connection.

This is the static entry for const ENTRIES = []

```
export const ENTRIES1 = [
{
    title: 'Beautiful and dramatic Antelope Canyon',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et nuncat mergitur',
    illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/UYiroysl.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'Earlier this morning, NYC',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/UPrs1EWl.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'White Pocket Sunset',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et nuncat ',
    illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/MABUbpDl.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'Acrocorinth, Greece',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet et nuncat mergitur',
    illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/KZsmUi2l.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'The lone tree, majestic landscape of New Zealand',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/2nCt3Sbl.jpg'
},
{
    title: 'Middle Earth, Germany',
    subtitle: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
    illustration: 'https://i.imgur.com/lceHsT6l.jpg'
}
];
```

I want to replace this with dynamic json data received from php.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetching a JSON can be done in the following way:

```
fetch('https://yoursite.com/your-json-creator.php')
  .then((responseJson) => {
    this.setState({entries: responseJson.entries});
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

For more information see the documentation for the [React Native Networking](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network) section.